# CSS Transform Rotate - Rendering Issue in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css, webkit, webkit-transform

I'm trying to rotate a div ( tag), via jQuery with the following code:

```
$(this).addClass("rotate1");

.rotate1{
-webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-moz-transform:  rotate(1deg);
-moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-o-transform: rotate(1deg);
-o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
-ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform: rotate(1deg);
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

But I'm having display issues, the  is't displayed fully.
Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CgPD/

The problem occurs only if I try to rotate the article by jQuery. If I assign it a css class with -webkit-transform..rotate... then it works fine.

The problem occurs in chrome, it is working fine in Firefox.

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery for rotation, I recommend using this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: @eivers88 nope, didn't work, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem because can't access jsfiddle today as it seems down (504).

Rather than add the class, I'd assign the transform inside the javascript, for example:

```
document.querySelector(this).style.webkitTransformOrigin = "0% 0%"
document.querySelector(this).style.webkitTransform = "rotate(1deg)"
```

I've found performing transforms and transitions directly in javascript makes the animation smoother on mobile devices.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. However If I add class by default in the html, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've been noticing that Chrome often has issues with double inheritance when it comes to the vendor prefixes, I had this issue recently with gradients. I had to drop the -webkit property which was acting redundant. I don't think that's the issue here, but I thought it worth bringing up.